# Auto complete search from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete

Eg:

```
**Category Table**

Catg_id   Catg_name    
-------------------
1         Bike  
2         Car  

**Company Table**    
Company_id   Company_name  
--------------------------
1             Bajaj
2             Honda   

**Company_category table**

com_catg_id   Company_id   Category_id
---------------------------------------
1              1            1
2              2            1
3              2            2

** Models table**
Model_id      Model_name    com_catg_id
----------------------------------------
1             Pulsar 220    1
2             Unicorn       2
3             City          3

**Purchase Table***

Purchase_id   Vehicle_No      Rate     model_id    status
-------------------------------------------------------  
1              KL 02 AN8306   50000    2           0
2              KL 10 AZ4764   120000   1           1
3              KL 04 AV8578   800000   3           1
```

These are 4 Database tables using.
I am using ajax for auto complete searching through a single field

eg: searching car,  want to list all cars in purchase table of status 1
if searching bike, want to list all bike in purchase table of status 1
search using company name, want to list all vehicle from that company in purchase table of status 1
same as search using model name, vehicle no,rate want to list matched items in purchase table

Please help me and please send a mysql query for implementing this.

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this tut](http://markonphp.com/autocomplete-php-jquery-mysql-part1/) 
This would surely help you.
This tutorial is for single field. It isn't hard to modify the code and use for multiple fields